# (mysql)Database migration difficulty when migrating from digikam 4.* to 5.*

Tags: mysql, image-processing, kde-plasma

I have ! a decade worth of tagged photographs managed with digikam and my debian stable/testing mix recently upgraded to digikam 5.*.

I now am facing the issue that the (mysql)database holding  that labor of love appears to be giving issues when trying to upgrade to the newer data base scheme (v.8).

When starting digikam v5.* pointed at the 4.*-used database backend I get the following:

```
digikam.dbengine: Loading SQL code from config file "/usr/share/digikam/database/dbconfig.xml"
digikam.dbengine: Checking XML version ID => expected:  3  found:  3
digikam.coredb: Core database: running schema update
digikam.coredb: Core database: have a structure version  7
digikam.coredb: Core database: makeUpdates  7  to  8
digikam.dbengine: Failure executing query:
 ""
Error messages: "QMYSQL: Unable to execute query" "Can't DROP 'Albums_AlbumRoots'; check that column/key exists" 1091 2
Bound values:  ()
digikam.dbengine: Error while executing DBAction [ "UpdateSchemaFromV7ToV8" ] Statement [ "ALTER TABLE Albums\n                                        DROP FOREIGN KEY Albums_AlbumRoots;" ]
digikam.coredb: Core database: schema update to V 8 failed!
digikam.coredb: Core database: cannot process schema initialization
```

When explicitly trying to use the db migration tool included into 5.* I end up with the error represented in the following image:
[image]

Can anyone help with decyphering what's going on here, respectively how to fix it?

Joh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem due to some inconsistencies in my old db. After fixing those (mainly deleting some dead references) an upgrade went through. I still seem to have another issue, but probably not related to the db.

This will show your the problems (should all be empty except the root tag):

taken from https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=355831#c73

```
select * from Images where album not in (select Albums.id from Albums);
select id, icon from Albums where icon != 0 and icon not in (select id from Images);
select * from Albums where Albums.albumRoot not in (select AlbumRoots.id from AlbumRoots);
select * from ImageHaarMatrix where imageid not in (select id from Images);
select * from ImageInformation where imageid not in (select id from Images);
select * from ImageMetadata where imageid not in (select id from Images);
select * from VideoMetadata where imageid not in (select id from Images);
select * from ImagePositions where imageid not in (select id from Images);
select * from ImageComments where imageid not in (select id from Images);
select * from ImageCopyright where imageid not in (select id from Images);
select * from Tags where pid != 0 and pid not in (select id from Tags);
select id, icon from Tags where icon != 0 and icon not in (select id from Images);
select * from ImageTags where tagid not in (select id from Tags);
select * from ImageTags where imageid not in (select id from Images);
select * from ImageProperties where imageid not in (select id from Images);
select * from ImageHistory where imageid not in (select id from Images);
select * from ImageRelations where subject not in (select id from Images);
select * from ImageRelations where object not in (select id from Images);
select * from ImageTagProperties where imageid not in (select id from Images);
select * from TagProperties where tagid not in (select id from Tags);
select * from ImageTagProperties where tagid not in (select id from Tags);
```

There is also a repair script to be found at the source.

And I just learned, that 5.2.0 has been released two days ago!

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. In my case your queries give:
`select * from ImageInformation where imageid not in (select id from Images);# 18 rows`
`select * from ImageMetadata where imageid not in (select id from Images);# 18 rows`
`select * from ImageComments where imageid not in (select id from Images);# 21 rows`
`select * from Tags where pid != 0 and pid not in (select id from Tags); # 1 row`
`select * from ImageTags where tagid not in (select id from Tags);# 8 rows`
`select * from ImageTags where imageid not in (select id from Images);# 111 rows`. Do I delete those rows?

Comment: For a "decade of labor of love" it seems to be only a small bit of loss, so I would just delete it. Of course I presume you have a backup of your current state of the db at a very secure place...

I would also look at the attachments https://bugs.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=99906 and https://bugs.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=99907 of the bug report - fixing the db prior to update atempts and manual update scripts.

Comment: Rereading your comment and deleting all rows but the one with the root tag produced by the code as well as stepping through the schema v.7 to v.8 upgrade code provided with the bug solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: ... problem solved, but just ushering in the next one ... now I have meta and thumb info on all my images, including those residing on network drives ... however, the paths to the network residing images seem shot and I can't access them ... when trying to e.g. add a directory/album there I'm being told that "file://<path to NAS missing here>/<parent of the dir to create>" does not exist ... did you encounter that as well?

Comment: I'd open another question for that.

Comment: My pictures only reside on a harddrive directly mounted, so the problem doesn't apply to me. Though, when I first started after the database had been rebuilt, it took digikam the whole night to go through all the albums. Just had finished this morning, and I didn't check since.

Comment: I have, in the meantime, inquired at the digikam mailing list and it turned out to be a case of wrongly encoded paths in the database (probably as a result of transitioning away from the kde to the qt api). After changing the html-encoded slashes ("/") in the path to the character itself, everything started to work.

Answer (score 3):

(Having a hard time migrating from Debian Wheezy to Debian Stretch, hope this helps someone...)

This worked for me:

- make sure digiKam is not running
- copy your old configuration file from `~/.kde/share/config/digikamrc` to `~/.config/digikamrc`
- open your `digikam4.db` database file with some sqlite editor (e.g. `sqlitebrowser`)
- edit table *AlbumRoots* and fix slashes in *identifier* column (i.e. replace all instances of `%2F` with `/`)

  ```
  UPDATE AlbumRoots
  SET identifier = replace(identifier, '%2F', '/')
  WHERE identifier LIKE '%%%2F%';
  ```
- save the database
- cross your fingers (optional, but recommended)
- start digiKam

Good luck!